# Why would a decorator only occasionally work in django?

Tags: python, django, view, decorator

I have a weird situation where I have a decorator on a django view that only works intermittently. When I reload the page the associated with the view it behaves as if there is not decorator on it. If I wait a while and then come back and refresh the page again the decorator will occasionally actually work. I have no idea what would be causing something like this. Any ideas? Has anyone else experienced this.

I know that the decorator is working sometimes because I have set break points in the decorator code and it will occasionally stop. Other times it will just reload the page normally as if there was no decorator.

Comment: A stripped down example would be helpful.

Comment: Maybe you're caching the view's response?

Comment: Spencer, care to respond? :)